# How to edit Java class for WSDL provided

Tags: java, oracle, web-services, soapui

I am working on a java program to call a Oracle Webservice in loop to create some data. But I have been told to use different XML tags that the ones that are provided on the WSDL.
So far, I have found no problems with this, since I learnt to "import" the WSDL url and create the java classes from it. 
But now, I face a problem that I don't know how to

So far, I have found no problems with this, since I learnt to "import" the WSDL url and create the java classes from it. 
But now, I face a problem that I don't know how to create this new tags on the Java classes, or even of this will work.

```
     <com:StandardReceiptFLEXVA>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <stan:CashReceiptId>?</stan:CashReceiptId>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <stan:__FLEX_Context>?</stan:__FLEX_Context>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <stan:__FLEX_Context_DisplayValue>? 
           </stan:__FLEX_Context_DisplayValue>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <stan:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>?</stan:_FLEX_NumOfSegments>
        </com:StandardReceiptFLEXVA>
```

This is the standard code that SOAPUI generates when I give the WSDL url. But Oracle support team (which I have contacted previously) have told me that I need to use this:

```
<com:StandardReceiptFLEXVA xsi:type="stan:Fianzas" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

           <stan:__FLEX_Context>FEE</stan:__FLEX_Context>
       <stan:modalidad>Provisional</stan:modalidad>
       <stan:tipoFianza>CASH</stan:tipoFianza>
       <stan:actividadConApbc>Test</stan:actividadConApbc>
           <stan:numReferenciaMigracion>99</stan:numReferenciaMigracion>


        </com:StandardReceiptFLEXVA>
```

That Works on SOAPUI, but when I go to my Java class, the are no set/get but the "standard" ones.. So I thought I should edit the java class and add these. But I don't know how to specify the xsi:type="stan:Fianzas" attribute on Java. I hope I managed to explained myself correctly, since I am not an English speaker.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The name of tag itself is different in two examples: stan:tipoFianza ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your new WSDL file is working fine in SoapUI, then now you new to (**re-generate**) the java client code from the new updated WSDL file.

You can achieve that in SoapUI itself by following the instructions given in below links. It basically shows you how you can use different code generation tools like Axis 1.X, Axis 2, CXF 2.X, and .NET 2.0 to generate client code.

[SOAP Code Generation](https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/soap-code-generation.html)

[Generating Client JAVA code for WSDL using SOAP UI](https://dzone.com/articles/generating-client-java-code)